# Dual-booting more than one Linux distro

Tags: dual-boot

I'm currently running Ubuntu 16.04 but would like to install another Linux distro by dual-boot. I tried installing another distro but during installation I realised that it had to also be root and this could not be allowed. How can I have both running on my machine?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to multiboot, you will need to create a partition for each distro's / (root) filesystem. You might also need a /home for each, to avoid different versions of applications getting confused over content in ~/.config and similar.

Comment: Take a look at the detailed answer to this question... It explains what I "think" you are concerned about. 

http://askubuntu.com/questions/896626/what-to-do-when-installing-two-distros-on-same-drive